# Error compiling C++ project, giving error permission denied collect.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Hello there I am currently getting into developing C++ applications and am using visual studio code with mingw compiler on windows. I built the application last night however now it's deciding to not let me build it again. The built file has disappeared from the directory, it's definitely isn't running in task manager and my antiviruses haven't quarantined it so I have ran out of ideas since this is my first application I have made.

[image: File isn't there]

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Did you see [this](https://geekthis.net/post/mingw-fix-permission-denied-ld-and-error/)?  Also why not try Visual Studio Community edition instead, which is a free industry-standard professional dev environment?

Comment: try deleting `a.exe`, something is probably using it, you could try [process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find what has an open handle to your file

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've tried the other options and still didn't work. I have however added another argument "-o a.exe" in the json file and this seems to work well.

Comment: I doubt this fixed your problem, it's just a coincidence

Comment: Well I can now compile it. I don't think you understand that there is no a.exe so your last comment was not helpful.

Comment: But `a` (`a.exe` on Windows) is the default output file, so this change is just a coincidence as @AlanBirtles mentioned.  Also did you read the link I put in my comment to your question?  More than likely you were still running `a.exe` while trying to recompile it.

Comment: Note that windows sometimes allows you to delete a locked file but wont then allow a new file to be created until the original file is unlocked

Comment: Yeah I read the links provided but still no luck with them however a simple restart of my computer seemed to fix it without declaring the name of the file with -o argument.

Answer (score 0):

shutdown your .exe file from the taskbar and delete it. And then rerun the process. It should work now.